# Pythonic way of using Python3's functools.singledispatch in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making the transition over to Python3 and have been exploring some of the functionality of the stdlib. [functools.singledispatch](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/) caught my eye and I've been playing around with it a little bit. However, at the point where I tried using it in a class I ran into some problems.

It doesn't appear to work with functions registered inside the class, you can make it work by directly calling fun.dispatch(type(arg))(argname=arg) and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

I tried using @classmethod and @staticmethod as decorators above and below the registration but that didn't work.

Here's a contrived example that registers handlers to convert the input argument when creating a class to ensure that it will always be a list.

```
from functools import singledispatch

class UrlDispatcher(object):

    @singledispatch
    def url_input(self, input):
        print('input wasn\'t dispatched', input)

    @url_input.register(str)
    def _(self, input):
        print('input is a str', input)
        self.input = [input]

    @url_input.register(list)
    def _(self, input):
        print('input is a list', input)
        self.input = input

    def __init__(self, arg):

        # Works, albeit clunkily
        self.url_input.dispatch(type(arg))(self,input=arg)

        # Always uses the base dispatcher
        self.url_input(input=arg)

a = "http://www.cnn.com"
b = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.slashdot.org"]

s1 = UrlDispatcher(a)
s2 = UrlDispatcher(b)
```

Comment: Well, the dispatch happens on the type of the first argument...which is `self`

Comment: Yeah, I get why it doesn't work - I'm interested in how it could work.

Comment: `x.y(z)` already performs single dispatch on the type of `x`. What you're trying to get is multiple dispatch. It makes sense that `functools.singledispatch` might not provide a natural solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - *you don't*.

http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/122554/

Quoting from a post I found at the above URL I think it's explained - short answer is 'generic functions' are for stateless algorithms. I was unaware of that definition.

> Correct. OO and generic functions are different development paradigms,
>   and there are limitations on mixing them. Generic functions are for
>   stateless algorithms, which expect to receive all required input
>   through their arguments. By contrast, class and instance methods
>   expect to receive some state implicitly - in many respects, they
>   *already are* generic functions.
>
> Thus, this is really a request for dual dispatch in disguise: you want
>   to first dispatch on the class or instance (through method dispatch)
>   and *then* dispatch on the second argument (through generic function
>   dispatch).
>
> Dual dispatch is much harder than single dispatch and
>   "functools.singledispatch" does not and should not support it (it's in
>   the name). As PJE noted, you *can* use singledispatch with
>   staticmethods, as that eliminates the dual dispatch behaviour by
>   removing the class and instance based dispatch step. You can also
>   register already bound class and instance methods as implementations
>   for a generic function, as that also resolves the dual dispatch in a
>   way that means the single dispatch implementation doesn't even need to
>   be aware it is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work. Whether or not it's the best solution, I don't know.

```
class Foo:
    def method(self, arg):
        _method(arg, self)

@functools.singledispatch
def _method(arg, self):
    ...

...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod

as of python 3.8 there is an stdlib function for method dispatching

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, work on any Python (3.8 or less)

```
class MyClass:  

    def over_ride_func( self, arg):
        if type(arg) is list:
            self.over_ride_func_list (arg)
            
        if type(arg) is int:
            self.over_ride_func_int (arg)       

        if type(arg) is float:
            self.over_ride_func_float (arg)     

        if type(arg) is str:
            self.over_ride_func_string (arg)        
            
    def over_ride_func_list(self, arg ):
        print ("List arg: ", arg, " with legnth", len(arg), " first item", arg[0])

    def over_ride_func_int(self, arg ):
        print ("int arg: ", arg)

    def over_ride_func_float(self, arg ):
        print ("Float arg: ", arg)

    def over_ride_func_string(self, arg ):
        print ("String arg ", arg)


obj_myclass = MyClass()
obj_myclass.over_ride_func(665)
obj_myclass.over_ride_func(444.31)
obj_myclass.over_ride_func([3,5,6])
obj_myclass.over_ride_func("Hello over ride function")
```